# How to sort Google Account on Setting

Tags: sync, email, google-account

lot of email currently signed in to my phone.
I accidently remove my email due Google Play Games problem. I want to my email back at top on list.

Is there any a way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Which Android device and Android version are you using? Is it rooted?

Comment: If the device is rooted, change the order in the column `_id` of table `accounts` for your Google accounts in the database located at `/data/system/users/0/accounts.db`. Reboot and it would work. I successfully tested this on Android 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove all of the other accounts and then add back the one you want first before the others.  There is no way to re-order accounts that have already been added.

Comment: that's the one I want to avoid.